# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Every beta site, when it becomes public, decides on who it's moderators should be. This is done with input from the Stackexchange team.

Individuals can nominate themselves or others to be moderators. Third-party nominations must be accepted by the nominee to be valid.

As Tim Post has said, moderators need three qualifications:

- Consistently patient and fair when dealing with other users
- Have a little time each week to devote to moderating the site
- Willing to help jump start promotional activities, and guide new users as they find the site for the first time

It should be helpful to review Stack Exchange's [theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Good luck! Final decisions are made by SE.
**Edit:** I forgot to add this from Tim Post:

> Nominate below with whatever text you'd like to offer about yourself and why you want the job, and include a link to your profile on the main site. Do you feel strongly that someone else would be a great moderator? Feel free to nominate them as well, explaining why you feel strongly about them as a potential candidate, and link to their main profile as well.
>
> Third-party nominations need to be accepted by the person you nominate, they can either leave a comment to accept, or edit your post with whatever detail they wish to add.

**Edit:** There is more information on the moderator nomination process during the beta phase at [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore), including a [longer list of qualities](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/#moderators) for who would make a good moderator.  The linked page also specifies that the following text should be posted in any moderator nomination thread:

> Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.”

Comment: How many moderators are we looking for?

Comment: @Thomas expatriates SE is going into public beta as well, and they are looking for 3 moderators.

Comment: Is this question the official place for nominations?

Comment: @MattF. I asked Jon Ericson about when they will hold moderator elections. He replied, "Anybody can start the pro tem moderator question at any time. But if it's not there before the start of public beta, we'll kick it off."

Comment: I think it could be beneficial to have moderators from different time zones (i.e. we could take such info into account).

Comment: @BrianRushton I have edited your post with a link to the [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore) page (which is specifically for moderators during a public beta), and added the text requested there regarding self-nominations.  I have also flagged this post for moderator attention.

Comment: Incidentally, as far as I know none of the nominees so far (including myself) have experience as community moderators for a Stack Exchange site.  We are looking for three moderators, and I think it would be very helpful if at least one of the three has done this before.  If anyone who is active on this site has such experience and is willing to serve, please nominate yourself!

Answer (score 24):

I suggest [Sue VanHattum](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/60/sue-vanhattum). She is not only active in asking, answering, but working on developing the site here on meta.

Comment: Thank you for the nomination. I accept. I am new to Stack Exchange. I am very experienced in the blogging community, where there are lots of high school (secondary education) math teachers. I would like to help the culture here develop to be welcoming to people who are math educators at any level. Not sure how to "include a link to [my] profile on the main site".

Comment: @SueVanHattum András Bátkai's post already includes a link to your profile.

Comment: hee hee. And so does my comment.

Comment: Perhaps deleting "on the main site" would make that clearer. Unless you want us newbies to out ourselves. ;^)

Comment: @SueVanHattum  It's actually slightly different.  The link to your name at the end of your comment links to your profile on the meta site.  In particular, it lists the questions you have asked and answers that you have given on meta.  The link in in András Bátkai's post links to your profile on the main site, including questions you have asked and answers you have given there.  Both of these are helpful for the present purpose, but this is the reason for the "on the main site" language.

Answer (score 24):

I would like to nominate [Jim Belk](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/50/jim-belk). He was very involves in the conception of the site, from the very start on, and continued his involvement ever since.

There were already some occassion where he and I did not have the same opinion, but in all these situations of disagreement I felt his behavior was exmplary.
Thus, in addition to knowing from his contributions here and elsewhere that he is knowlegable and passionate about communicating mathematics, I feel I can also claim from first hand experience that he has the right personality to moderate a site.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words.  I happily accept this nomination.

Comment: As quid mentions, I was [involved in the definition and commitment phases](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/101185/jim-belk), including the [vote to decide the name](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/13356/vote-here-to-decide-the-name).  I am also active on Math Stack Exchange ([user page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1726/jim-belk)) and Math Overflow ([user page](http://mathoverflow.net/users/6514/jim-belk)), though I do not have any moderation experience on either of those sites.

Comment: I was also involved in promoting this site on the math education subreddit (see [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/matheducation/comments/1w4xgj/new_qa_site_for_mathematics_education_on_the/)), Math Stack Exchange and Math Overflow (see my answers [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12555/proposal-for-mathematics-learning-studying-and-education) and [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1426/proposal-for-mathematics-learning-studying-and-education))

Comment: As someone who found out about this on /r/math, thanks for that!

Comment: @brendansullivan07  You're welcome.  Note, however, that it was Brian Rushton who advertised on /r/math (see [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1w5vpq/proposal_for_new_math_teachingpedagogy/) and [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1z090k/thanks_rmath_for_one_of_the_fastestgrowing/)). I cross-posted to /r/matheducation.

Comment: Ah I see. I remember seeing both at the same time, pretty much, so either way it was helpful :)

Comment: I'd like to point to the contrast between my response and Jim's response at the following (now closed) question, in support of his nomination: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/823/how-to-beat-procrastination

Answer (score 18):

I nominate [quid](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/143/quid). He was very active in beta phase, made a lot of (good) contribution in meta discussions and has expercience on Stack Exachange (is activly participation on MO.SE).

Comment: Thank you for the nomination, this is very kind. I enjoy contributing to this site even more than I thought before it started. I would be happy to contribute to it as a moderator, and thus *accept* the nomination. (I will write one or two follow up comments 'about me' to give some info not directly or not at all visible from my profile.)

Comment: On SE: I am mainly active on MO, but there quite a bit. Besides a solid score (about top 50) I am very involved in other aspects (some "highlights" currently 2nd by edits, 2nd by approving edits, 1st on meta [sorry if this comes of as strange but I am not sure how to convey this otherwise]). I also *used to be* **very** active in open/close moderation there. But I came to realize it is not optimal if this activity is 'monopolized', not even if it is just by being active and quick, and certainly not by being designated as moderator. So, I do not vote much any more there (cont.)

Comment: but continue to be active in debates that arise around these issues. I think some find me sometimes too argumentative or too involved in discussions. There might be some truth to this, but it is more excitement and passion about the sites than some aggressivenes. Still, I would pay some extra attention not to be perceived as too dominating,  whould I be desiganted a moderator. In addtion to my activity on MO I also believe to have a solid grasp of math.SE, though I have only a few point there but I passively follow their meta. (cont.)

Comment: Finally, I believe I can claim I am pretty familiar with the software. Having used the 10k+ tools since quite a while. Having stressed experience on other sites, let me add that I do realize this site will not and should not be like the oher math sites. Still I think some lessons learned there can be useful.

Comment: In real live: I choose to use SE under a pseudonym, even against some oppositionn on MO, mainly since I believe that on a SE sites the focus should be on contributions *there*, not merits and qualifications elsewhere, but perhaps still some remarks are in order (also to specify time zone): I am a central European (so UTC +1 or +2, depending on season) mathematician permanently employed at a research university; so teaching/research split about 50/50, teaching mainly for math students (but also exprience with computer science and engineering students).

Comment: I hope the aboce, which got a bit longer than intended, provides a meaningfum picture of me as an SE user. Feel free to ask for further information if you feel something is missing.

Comment: As quid mentions, he was quite active during the definition and commitment phases on Area 51 ([link to his user page](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/users/101186/quid)) as well as on Math Overflow ([user page](http://mathoverflow.net/users/9072/quid)) and Math Stack Exchange ([user page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/85306/quid)).  In particular, he has made an impressive [225 reviews](http://mathoverflow.net/users/9072/quid?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=11) on Math Overflow.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to nominate [Joel David Hamkins](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/90/joel-david-hamkins).

I hope he accepts the "ethical responsibility" of leading us to an ideal "friendly" forum because I strongly believe that this forum is special by its nature and so it needs special moderators particularly when we are at the beginning of building "the culture of MESE". We need moderators who believe on "soft" contribution and have enough "patience" to hear different opinions.

As the top user of Mathoverflow there is no need to enumerate the benefits of having such a moderator in MESE but I would like to emphasize that beside his "infinite" enthusiasm for helping people in any possible way and his continuous presence in both MESE and MO forums, what makes him "absolutely ideal" for being a moderator of MESE (and also MO!) is the way which he contributes with people in different categories including students, teachers and anybody else. Once I described this culture as "the true morale of Mathoverflow".

Good luck for all candidates!

Comment: Thank you very much for the nomination and for your kind words. I regret, however, that I'm unable to accept the nomination. Meanwhile, I do plan to participate on the site.

Answer (score 4):

I nominate [Brian Rushton](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/78/brian-rushton). He has been one of the most active users on Meta.MESE, as well as consistently providing the site with good questions and answers.

Comment: Thank you for your nomination! Because I will be finishing my postdoc soon, I will not be able to spend consistent time here after a few months. I feel I could not moderate well under those circumestances.

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a little late, but I'd also like to nominate [Brendan Sullivan](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/80/brendansullivan07) as a moderator. I've been impressed by his tact and his contributions to the site.

Comment: Thank you, I would be happy to help out in the moderator role! I don't have as much SE experience as others, but I have been involved with all stages of the site so far, have contributed (what I hope are) high quality questions and answers, and have spread the word about the site to friends and colleagues. No matter what, I'm just excited to see this community flourish.

Comment: @brendansullivan07 Looks like I was hours too late! I'll definitely nominate you and vote you next time an opening comes up.

Comment: Aha, thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I nominate [Joe Taxpayer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/64/joetaxpayer), as someone who is very familiar with Stack Exchange, and who would be a nice balance against all of the grad students and college professors.