# Nomination Suggestions for 2019 Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

We have an election that is currently live, looking for self-nominations.

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election

Is there anyone you think should nominate themselves, that has not stepped forward yet? There is no official way to nominate others, and that user will have to nominate themselves to be considered. Still, if you have someone in mind, could you **link their user page and say a few words about what you've seen**?

See also [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) for details on how SE thinks about moderation, and possibly [the original moderator nomination thread for this site](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/who-should-our-moderators-be).

Answer (score 3):

I'd like [Tommi Brander](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/2083/tommi-brander) to nominate themselves as moderator. Tommi is seemingly everywhere, leaving patient, helpful comments and edits to improve the quality of questions on the site.

I recommend you check out [Tommi's Activity Tab](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/2083/tommi-brander?tab=activity), where you can see a tireless number of comments and edits:

> Could you expand your answer a little bit?
>
> replaced editorial remarks with headings
>
> As per comments of @Namaste, the question would be improved by specifying what you mean by tutoring and perhaps specifying the country, too.
>
> as per SE guidelines, be nice; do not assume motivations, but rather ask.
>
> Questions are supposed to rely on personal experience or reliable sources, so mentioning the experience, if only tangentially related, is good and improves the credibity of the answer.

that seem to me to exemplify the Theory of Moderation of StackExchange sites.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. I nominated myself.

Comment: That's quite the endorsement, he might just have my vote.